# Real-valued bounded analytic functions on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, blaschke-products

Let $f: \overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a real (positive) valued function on the closed unit disc that is bounded and analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ (open unit disc) and
$$\lim_{|z| \to 1}f(z) = 1.$$
Can we conclude that $f(z) \leq 1$ in the whole disc?

I'm aware of a Blaschke product type argument that says that a function that is of unit modulus on the boundary, and bounded and analytic in the interior of the disc must have finitely many zeroes and hence must be a finite Blaschke product - however, can we ensure that a Blaschke product is always real valued? And if so, what does this say about the bound on $f$ in the interior of the disc?

EDIT:
An alternative formulation to the above, would be to consider the function $|f|$ where $f$ is an analytic, bounded function on the interior of the disc and continuous and bounded on the boundary with
$$\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| =1.$$
Similar to the above, the question would now concern the bound on $|f|$.

Comment: Edit: Reading the question again, the only analytic function with a purely real image would be a constant so yes, that inequality is trivially true because that means $f=1$

Comment: Thank you @NinadMunshi! I have actually added an edit to the question in response to your previous comment which adds a bit more of a substantial query. Though, your answer may well be enough for my problem!

Comment: @OlivierRoche No that is not analytic. One definition of analytic is that $f\in \text{ker}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\right)$ but for your function, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \neq 0$

Comment: I hoped the function $z \mapsto 2 - |z|$ would give a counterexample but this fails since it isn't continuously differentiable in $0$. 

I think the function $f : z \mapsto 2 - \cos (|z|\cdot \frac{\pi}{2})$ might do the trick,  but I'm too lazy to check if $f$ is analytic. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the edited question is YES.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq 1+\epsilon$ for $|z| \geq 1-\delta$. By MMP applied to the disk of radius $1-\delta$ we get  $|f(z)| \leq 1+\epsilon$ whenever $|z| \leq 1-\delta$. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is MMP? (My complex analysis is abysmal)

Comment: MMP stands for Maximum Modulus Principle.  According to this theorem if $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $|z|=R$ then $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $|z|\leq R$.

Comment: Ah okay, so this immediately just gives that since $|f(z)| \leq1$ on $|z|=1$, then $|f(z)| \leq 1$ also for $|z|\leq 1$?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to use a more complicated argument. This is because $f$ is only given to be analytic in the open set $(|z|<1)$ and the circle $|z|=1$ is not inside this open set , so MMP cannot be applied directly.  @CS1994

Comment: Could the Blaschke product argument not work in this scenario? Here we have an analytic function $f$ in the open disc that has the limit as stated in the question. This implies that $f$ must have finite number of zeroes and be of the form of a finite Blaschke product (see Fatou for the well-known result). A property of a finite Blaschke product is that its modulus is at most 1 in the interior of the disc. The proof of Fatou's result looks similar to the logic you are using here.
@kaviramamurthy

Comment: @CS1994 Balshke product argument works but is it really simpler than MMP argument?

Comment: It isn't - your argument is much more streamlined. Thanks for your help :)